# Android - GenericJson with nested info and arrays

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, nested

Let's say that I have a GenericJson var called myJson containing a Json message like this one:

```
{
  "id": "1234567890",
  "media": [{"id": "...", "url": "..."}, {"id": "...", "url": "..."}],
  "related_object": {"id": "...", "name": "..."}
}
```

If I want to get "id" value, I just write:

```
String myId = (String) myJson.get("id").
```

But what if I want to get the values inside of the nested content?

I tried with:

```
GenericJson[] myMedia = myJson.get("media");
GenericJson[] myMedia = (GenericJson[]) myJson.get("media");
```

but doesn't seem to like the casting.

Tried with ArrayList and works.

```
ArrayList<GenericJson> myMediaList = (ArrayList<GenericJson>) myJson.get("media");
```

but at that point I can't take anything out of the ArrayList...I tried with something like:

```
GenericJson[] myMedia = myMediaList.toArray();
GenericJson[] myMedia = (GenericJson[]) myMediaList.toArray();
```

or even something like

```
GenericJson myFirstMedia = myMediaList.get(0);
GenericJson myFirstMedia = (GenericJson) myMediaList.get(0);
```

but doesn't want to work...... even tho it's an ArrayList of GenericJson objects, nothing.

what should I do? is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

**I have written this function to read jsonobject dynamically Try this**

```
private void parseJson(JSONObject data) {

        if (data != null) {
            Iterator<String> it = data.keys();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();

                try {
                    if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray arry = data.getJSONArray(key);
                        int size = arry.length();
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            parseJson(arry.getJSONObject(i));
                        }
                    } else if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        parseJson(data.getJSONObject(key));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("" + key + " : " + data.optString(key));
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    System.out.println("" + key + " : " + data.optString(key));
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```